# Wordpress New Post Edit Toolbar is Missing

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

**Symptom:**
When I start a new post on my Wordpress (example: http://website.com/wp-admin/post-new.php), I have the following problems:

1. The tinyMCE editing toolbar is missing, and
2. Text does not appear when typed in the body of the new post

**Attempts:**
Following Wordpress' guidelines, I tried the following without success:

- Deactivate all plugins -- still no edit toolbar.
- Use other browsers -- same error in Chrome, Firefox, and IE on multiple machines.
- Enable SCRIPT_DEBUG in wp-config.php -- same error.
- Viewing browser errors in Chrome -- see below.

I opened Developer Tools ("F12") in Chrome on the new post page and found the following 3 errors:

1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) -- [wordpress-website]/wp-includes/js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js?ver=349-20805
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined -- wp-langs-en.js:1
3. Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined -- post-new.php:760

**Question:**
What must I do to get the edit toolbar back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 errors are an indication files may be missing. Have you verified the files haven't accidentally been moved or deleted?

Comment: I checked the files in ~/wp-includes/js/tinymce and noticed one was missing: tiny_mce.js. Figures! I uploaded the file and the edit toolbar is working again. Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the contents of the `wp-includes/` directory where TinyMCE is located. You can either do this via the admin area updater, or you can do it manually.

**Automatic way**

- Log into your WordPress admin area
- Navigate to Home > Updates
- Click the *Re-install Now* button

**Manual way**

- [Download](https://wordpress.org/download/) a copy of the version of WordPress you are currently
  running (if you are not running the current version you can find a copy in the [release archive](https://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/))
- FTP into your site
- Make a backup of your `wp-content/` directory
- Delete the `wp-includes/` directory from the server
- Upload the entire `wp-includes/` directory from the new copy of WordPress you downloaded

You should now have a completely replaced `wp-content/` directory and all of the TinyMCE files will be on your server.